# C# and ActiveSync communication / open and read files

Tags: c#, sockets, usb, windows-ce, activesync

I have a device connected to a host computer through cradle usb. Now, I'm just wondering if I could use C# sockets to communicate with the device (ie device sending data, host computer processing it then replying back to the device). How can I accomplish this? by that, what ip address etc etc.. do I have to change so that it would connect cause I have the sockets working on wireless. If not, then is there a way to connect to the device, open and read a file (a text document to be more specific) from the device to my host application.. any ideas?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your target device, when you connect via ActiveSync it likely makes a local RNDIS network connection between teh two devices.  You can resolve "ppp_peer" as the partner's network name instead of trying to use a hard-coded IP address (IIRC the IP is different on XP than on Vista).

Be aware that it's not a full connection.  TCP packets gets passed through, but things like ICMP do not.

Of course, this just gives you a socket connection, just like if you were to connect between two PCs.  It's not going to allow you to do file system operations unless you have an app on the other side listening for commands.  If you want that type of thing, Microsoft provides the [Remote API (RAPI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920274.aspx) interface ([wrapped in managed code here](http://rapi.codeplex.com/))for a lot of basic commands, and it can be [extended (with C)](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2007/07/27/HOWTORetrieveTheDeviceIDFromTheDesktop.aspx) to do anything you'd like.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the response. Ok, So if I have a client (which is on the device) trying to create a socket connection with the host (desktop computer) how do i initialize my IPendpoint if they are only connected through cradle usb. Cause if i have it on wireless. I do it like this  IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(addr, 1666); addr being the ip address of the host then just the matter of binding it with the socket during beginconnect.